# Convert a dictionary of strings and lists to a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with values in ints, bools, and strings and lists and a sorted list of keys in which I want the final list of lists.
I want the output such that the where there a lists we make combinations of that with single values.

Input:

```
cols = ['region', 'city', 'country', 'valid'] 
vals = {'city': [10, 20], 'valid': True, 'region': 3, 'country': 'US'}
```

Output:

```
[[3, 10, 'US', True], [3, 20, 'US', True]]
```

Now if another field is a list, it would increase the combinations.

Input:

```
cols = ['region', 'city', 'country', 'valid'] 
vals = {'city': [10, 20], 'valid': True, 'region': [3, 4], 'country': 'US'}
```

Output:

```
[[3, 10, 'US', True], [3, 20, 'US', True], [4, 10, 'US', True], [4, 20, 'US', True]]
```

Looking for the most pythonic way to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

cols = ['region', 'city', 'country', 'valid'] 
vals = {'city': [10, 20], 'valid': True, 'region': [3, 4], 'country': 'US'}

values = [vals[key] for key in cols]
values = [val if isinstance(val, list) else [val] for val in values]

result = list(itertools.product(*values))
print(result)
# [(3, 10, 'US', True), (3, 20, 'US', True), (4, 10, 'US', True), (4, 20, 'US', True)]
```

Related reading:

- [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (what `*values` is doing in `itertools.product(*values)`)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.product` for the respective fields like,

But before doing the `product`, you need to check if it an instance of `int`, or `str`, if yes, then convert those to a `list` or `tuple` for the sake of correct iteration

```
>>> vals = {'city': [10, 20], 'valid': True, 'region': 3, 'country': 'US'}
>>> 
>>> city = vals['city']
>>> region = vals['region']
>>> country = vals['country']
>>> 
>>> if not isinstance(region, (list, tuple)):
...   region = [region]
... 
>>> if not isinstance(country, (list, tuple)):
...   country = [country]
... 
>>> list(product(region, city, country, [vals['valid']]))
[(3, 10, 'US', True), (3, 20, 'US', True)]


>>> vals
{'city': [10, 20], 'valid': True, 'region': [3, 4], 'country': 'US'}
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(vals['region'], vals['city'], [vals['country']], [vals['valid']]))
[(3, 10, 'US', True), (3, 20, 'US', True), (4, 10, 'US', True), (4, 20, 'US', True)]
```

You could write a function to handle that like,

```
$ cat mkcomb.py
from itertools import product


def mk_comb(keys, vals):
    values = [
      vals[key] if isinstance(vals[key], (list, tuple)) else [vals[key]]
      for key in keys
    ]
    return list(product(*values))

cols = ['region', 'city', 'country', 'valid'] 
vals1 = {'city': [10, 20], 'valid': True, 'region': 3, 'country': 'US'}
vals2 = {'city': [10, 20], 'valid': True, 'region': [3, 4], 'country': 'US'}
print(mk_comb(cols, vals1))
print(mk_comb(cols, vals2))
```

Output:

```
$ python mkcomb.py
[(3, 10, 'US', True), (3, 20, 'US', True)]
[(3, 10, 'US', True), (3, 20, 'US', True), (4, 10, 'US', True), (4, 20, 'US', True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension can do the job for you:

```
list(itertools.product(*[vals[c] if type(vals[c]) == list else [vals[c]] for c in cols]))
```